# Artisan uncaught exception 'ReflectionException'

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-4, composer-php

I am running Ubuntu64 vagrant/virtualbox with devbox from https://github.com/Aboalarm/devbox

This box has worked with other development environments for this particular software.  The application uses angularjs and laravel4.  When installed on the box, I can get composer updated with:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

but without that flag, I get a PHP fatal error.  This is my composer.json:

```
{
        "require": {
                "laravel/framework": "dev-master",
                "cartalyst/sentry": "2.1.*",
                "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
                "mews/phpthumb": "dev-master",
                "tecnick.com/tcpdf": "6.0.059",
                "pda/pheanstalk": "dev-master"
        },
        "autoload": {
                "classmap": [
                        "app/commands",
                        "app/controllers",
                        "app/models",
                        "app/libraries",
                        "app/database/migrations",
                        "app/database/seeds",
                        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
                ]
        },
        "scripts": {
                "post-update-cmd": "php artisan optimize"
        },
        "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

when I leave off the --no-scripts flag, or when I try to do anything with artisan, ie

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class path.config does not exist' in /var/www/marketing.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:628
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/marketing.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(628): ReflectionClass->__construct('path.config')
#1 /var/www/marketing.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(550): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('path.config', Array)
#2 /var/www/marketing.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(472): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('path.config', Array)
#3 /var/www/marketing.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(962): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('path.config')
#4 /var/www/marketing.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(1011): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('path.config')
#5 /var/www/marketing.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/ in /var/www/marketing.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 628
```

The web application does load in my browser.  However, I just cannot do anything artisan-specific, like migrations.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that you install laravel5 and it changes a bit in the structure. Be sure to read this http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade, `paths` in particular

Comment: Good catch.  That would explain the timing issues - I didn't realize that laravel's dev-master was now pointing to laravel5.  I changed the version in my composer.json and it seems to be working.

Comment: It's not about `dev-master` but rather `minimum-stability: dev`. If it wasn't for the latter, you'd still get `4.2@dev`