# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException'

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I got this similar error ([Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918088/artisan-uncaught-exception-reflectionexception/)) when running php codes. But I had no luck to fix it yet.

```
Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class path.base does not exist' in /home/localblu/staging/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:504 Stack trace: 

#0 /home/localblu/staging/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(504): ReflectionClass->__construct('path.base') 

#1 /home/localblu/staging/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(428): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('path.base', Array) 

#2 /home/localblu/staging/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(462): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('path.base', Array)

#3 /home/localblu/staging/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(806): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('path.base')

#4 /home/localblu/staging/bootstrap/start.php(11): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('path.base') 

#5 /home/localblu/staging/public/index.php(35): require_once('/home/localblu/...') 

#6 {main} thrown in /home/localblu/staging/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 504
```

And this is my composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
    "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "~2.3"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
```

}

Could you guys help me on this?

Comment: Did you run a `composer dump-autoload`?

Answer (score 0):

run

```
 composer dump-autoload
```

as mentioned in the comment or

```
 composer dump-autoload -o
```

This solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel project folder and go to `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`
and please comment the line `app('sneaker')->captureException($exception);`
Then you will get the exact error and then resolve the error